# How to add download link in mail for attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Is it possible to "download" the attachment with link in mail. without sending user to server to download as the attachment itself is a part of mail.

I have added attachment to the mail using

```
attachments["filename.pdf"] = File.open(pdf_fil)
```

The thing i want to know is that can we add "download" link in mail for this attachment as below. Which i tried but doesn't work.

```
 link_to("Download", attachments["filename.pdf"].url)
```

Like we display image in view from attachment as

```
image_tag(attachments["filename.png"].url)
```

Comment: If you want to attach a file to an email: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. We here not to implement your tasks, but to help find mistakes in you existed approaches.

Comment: I know and have implemented the attachment to the mail. But the question is I want to show the link in mail to download that attachment explicitly

Comment: Have edited the question hope this is clear, what my problem is.

Comment: As I see it, either you have a classic email attachment in the email, and then your client have it displayed according to its email software / website, or you have a link to the file in your server.

You can't have it like you describe.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible

Answer (score 3):

Just spotted this question and although it is quite old, I am answering it for the benefit of others.

I had a similar scenario, where I wanted the inline displayed image to trigger the download of an attached PDF file. The image was the preview of the PDF attachment.

So, this is possible, but not with the `link_to` helper. Just plain HTML. Something like this I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
<a href="<%= attachments['image.jpg'].url %>">
  <%= image_tag attachments['image.jpg'].url %>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Ilias. But, this doesn't work: 
When opening the link on Gmail: "We’re sorry, but your account is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience and suggest trying again in a few minutes". When opening the link on AppleMail: "There is no application set to open the URL cid:@MacBook-Pro.local.mail."